# JSDoc - Is it possible to make one-integrated-html document?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I made my Javascript API document with JSDoc.
After made them, the directory ./docs generated where my well-made JSDoc document is in.

But I think, there are too diverse and various files like icons, scripts, styles, html files for each .js file..... etc.

Is there any beautiful-simple way to make these files into one-integrated-html files like [Redoc](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/) which is the best API documentation tool (for me :-D)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create api docs by using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc

It will take in all your JavaScript files that have the jsdoc comments in them and convert them to a swagger api docs.

The only caveat is that your jsdoc setup needs to support the swagger spec to work properly

Here is the getting started for examples on the jsdoc setup

https://github.com/Surnet/swagger-jsdoc/blob/master/docs/GETTING-STARTED.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Is there any example page or document that swagger-jsdoc applied?

Comment: Basically all it does is get you the swagger specs in one json format. Then you can use Redoc to prettify it. Since you said you liked redoc, then this is an option. The caveat is that you’ll need to create the endpoint to provide redoc with the json output dynamically that swagger jsdoc provides you. Cheers!

Comment: Or instead of giving redoc the endpoint, you could generate the static json file prior to building anything and provide that to redoc

Comment: Then what do you think the advantages of doing so, compared with just writing my javascript API's spec in yaml so that I can make a real-Redoc document?

Comment: Advantages of jsdoc is that you are both documenting your code and exposing a way for external users to see your api definitions through this setup. Basically the api spec is closer to the code so you don’t have to jump files to review this while coding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some changes in  tmpl and publish.js files to generate single html file

1. Example:- use docdash template to modify those files.
2. In jsdoc.json template:{'use your customized template which is in your project directory'}